# If hypothesis class is agnostic PAC-learnable it is PAC-learnable

Tags: machine-learning

I'm trying to prove formaly this claim, given that $\mathcal{H}$ is a hypothesis class of binary classifiers.

According to the definition, Hypothesis class $\mathcal{H}$ is agnostic PAC-learnable with respect to $ \mathcal{Z}=\mathcal{X}\times \mathcal{Y}$, if exists a function $ m_\mathcal{H}:(0,1)^2\rightarrow \mathbb{N}$ and algorithm $\mathcal{A} $, such that for every distribution $\mathcal{D}$ over $\mathcal{Z}$ - $ \mathbb{P}_{S\sim \mathcal{D}^m}[L_\mathcal{D} (\mathcal{A}(S))\leq min_{h\in \mathcal{H}}(h) +\epsilon ]\ge 1- \delta$.

---

Proving effort-

- Assuming that that the target function $f\in \mathcal{H}$, i know
  that $min_{h\in \mathcal{H}}(h)=0.$
- Lets look at the set $\{(x,y)|f(x)=y\}$. Obviously $\mathcal{Z}'\subseteq\mathcal{Z}$.
- Suppose $ \mathcal{D}'=\mathcal{D} |_{\mathcal{Z}'}$.

Is it sufficent to show that $\mathcal{Z}$ - $ \mathbb{P}_{\mathcal{D}'^m}[L_{\mathcal{D}'} (\mathcal{A}(S))\leq\epsilon ]\ge 1- \delta$? If yes, why?

Assuming that it may be sufficent, how can i show that given $S\sim \mathcal{D}^m$, the event $ \{L_\mathcal{D} (\mathcal{A}(S))\leq min_{h\in \mathcal{H}}(h) +\epsilon \} $ equals to the event  $\{L_{\mathcal{D}'} (\mathcal{A}(S))\leq\epsilon \}$ and this complete the proof -

According to the first bullet: $ \{L_\mathcal{D} (\mathcal{A}(S))\leq min_{h\in \mathcal{H}}(h) +\epsilon \} $ =$ \{L_\mathcal{D} (\mathcal{A}(S))\leq\epsilon \} $. But what is the relation between $L_\mathcal{D} (\mathcal{A}(S))$ and $L_\mathcal{D'} (\mathcal{A}(S))$.

Comment: You haven't used $m_\mathcal{H}$ in your definition.

Comment: What you need to show is that there exists $m(\epsilon,\delta)$ such that for every target concept $h\in\mathcal{H}$ and every distribution $\mathcal{D}$ over $\mathcal{X}$, If $|S|\ge m(\epsilon,\delta)$ then $\Pr\left[\mathcal{L}_\mathcal{D}\left(\mathcal{A}(S)\right)\le \epsilon \right]\ge 1-\delta$.